# How to use select_related

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

How do I use `select_related` to get the first and last name of the employee class below.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    """
    Model, which holds general information of an employee.

    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='users',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    photo_logo = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

#### Here is how I have implemented my query

```
emp=Employee.objects.filter(pk=1).select_related('user').values('user_first_name','user_last_name','id')
```

But I get the following logs after running a print statement in  `django shell`

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'user_first_name' into field. Choices are: address, address_id, attendance, basic,
```

Comment: `emp=Employee.objects.filter(pk=1).select_related('user').values('user__first_name','user__last_name','id')`
You need to use double underscore to access related model fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should use `__` for relation `field`

```
emp=Employee.objects.filter(pk=1).select_related(
     'user'
).values('user__first_name','user__last_name','id')
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you need specific fields of user model, you dont need `select_related` in this case, just use:

```
emp=Employee.objects.filter(pk=1).values('user__first_name','user__last_name','id')
```

query.

Note that you shoulduse double underscore `__` to perform join.